# OSX pushing pixels to screen with minimum latency

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, draw, low-latency

I'm trying to develop some very low-latency graphics applications and am getting really frustrated by how long it takes to draw to screen through OpenGL. Every discussion I find about it online addresses optimizing the OpenGL pipeline, but doesn't get anywhere near the results that I need.

Check this out:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbz4bq67cxluhs7/MouseLatency.MOV?dl=0

You probably noticed this before: With a c++ OpenGL app, dragging the mouse around the screen, and drawing the mouse location in OpenGL, the OpenGL lags behind by 3 or 4 frames. Clearly OSX *CAN* draw [the cursor] to screen with very low latency, but OpenGL is much slower. So let's say I don't need to do any fancy OpenGL rendering. I just want to push pixels to screen somehow. Is there a way for me to bypass OpenGL completely and draw to screen faster? Or is this kind of functionality going to be locked inside the kernel somewhere that I can't reach it?

Comment: Try to give more detail on what you have tried already, possibly some code examples of your implementation

Comment: Might want to give [this buffer object streaming article](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) a read. I'd speculate that the completely-bypass-opengl way would involve hardware-dependent APIs.

Comment: Under OSX El Capitan its possible to use a simple 4 vertex shader with a pixel shader to draw from a frame buffer using Metal. See example http://www.objc.io/issues/18-games/metal/

Comment: I looked through the buffer streaming article, but I haven't been able to get it to help me. The only way I can see to use it to see an improvement is if I'm somehow able to directly access the drawn memory post-openGL and redraw to it outside of the openGL pipeline. But I don't think this is the solution I'm looking for...

Comment: When I turn off vsync, suddenly my latency basically drops to zero. Maybe it's that I'm still waiting for the buffer to flip 3 or 4 times, but with vsync off this happens every 3 ms  instead of every 16ms?

Answer (score 3):

datenwolf's answer is excellent. I just wanted to add one thing to this discussion regarding triple buffering at the compositor level, since I am very familiar with the Microsoft Windows desktop compositor.

*I know you are asking about OS X here, but the implementation details I am going to discuss are the most sensible way of implementing this stuff and I would expect to see other systems work this way too.*

Triple buffering as you might enable at the application level adds a third buffer to the swap-chain that is synchronized to refresh. That way of doing triple buffering does add latency, because that third buffer has to be displayed and nothing is allowed to touch it until this happens (this is D3D's mandated behavior -- *the behavior and feature itself are undefined in OpenGL*); but the way the Desktop Window Manager (Windows) works is slightly different.

The behavior I have seen most drivers implement for desktop composition is frame dropping. Any situation where multiple frames are finished between refreshes, all but 1 of those frames are discarded. You actually get lower latency using a window rather than fullscreen + triple buffering, because it does not block buffer swaps when the third buffer (owned by the compositor) has a finished frame waiting to be displayed.

It creates a whole different set of visual issues if framerate is not reasonably consistent. Technically, pixels belonging to dropped frames have infinite latency, so the benefits from latency reduction done this way might be worthless if you needed every single frame drawn to appear on screen.

I believe you can get this behavior on OS X (if you want it) by disabling VSYNC and drawing in a window. VSYNC basically only serves as a form of frame pacing *(trade latency for consistency)* in this scenario and tearing is eliminated by the compositor itself regardless what rate you draw at.

---

#### Regarding mouse cursor latency:

The cursor in any modern window system will always track with minimum latency. There is literally a feature on graphics hardware called a "hardware cursor," where the driver stores the cursor position and then once per-refresh, has the hardware overlay the cursor on top of whatever is sitting in the framebuffer waiting to be scanned-out. So even if your application is drawing at 30 FPS on a 60 Hz display, the cursor is updated every 16 ms when the hardware cursor's used.

This bypasses all graphics APIs altogether, but is quite limited (e.g. it uses the OS-defined cursor).

---

#### TL;DR: Latency comes in many forms.

If your problem is input latency, then you can mitigate that by reducing the number of pre-rendered frames and avoiding triple buffering. *I could not begin to tell you how to reduce the number of driver pre-rendered frames on OS X.*

- Minimize length of time before something shows up on screen

If your problem is the amount of time that passes between executions of your render loop, you would go the other way. Increase pre-rendered frames, draw in a window and disable VSYNC. You may run into a lot of frames that are drawn but never displayed in this scenario.

- Minimize time spent blocking (increase FPS); some frames will never be displayed

Pre-rendered frames are a powerful little feature that you do not get control over at the OpenGL API level. It sets up how deeply the driver is allowed to pipeline everything and depending on the desired task you will trade different types of latency by fiddling with it. Many gamers swear by setting this value to 1 to minimize input latency at the cost of overall framerate "smoothness."

#### UPDATE:

Pre-rendered frames are one reason for your multi-frame delay. Fixing this in a cross-platform way is difficult (it's a driver setting), but if you have access to Fence Sync Objects you can produce the same behavior as forcing this to **1**.

I can explain this in more detail if need be, the general idea is that you insert a fence sync after the buffer swap and then wait for it to be signaled before the first command in the next frame is allowed to begin. Performance may take a nose dive, but latency will be minimized since the CPU won't be rendering ahead of the GPU anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of latencies at play here.

- **Input event → drawing state latency**

In your typical interactive application you have a event loop that usually goes

1. collect user input
2. process user input
3. determine what's to be drawn
4. draw to the back buffer
5. swap back to front buffer

With the usual ways in which event–update–display loops are written there's almost no delay between step 5 of the previous and step 1 of the following iteration. which means that steps 2, 3, and 4 operate with data that lags about one frame period behind.

So this is the first source of latency.

- **Tripple buffering / composition latency**

Many graphics pipelines enable triple buffering for smoother display update. Instead of keeping only a back and a front buffer around, there's also a third buffer inbetween. The *average* rate at which to these buffers is drawn is the display refresh period. The buffers themself are stepped at exactly the display refresh period. So this adds another frame period of latency.

If you're running on a system with a window compositor (which is the default by MacOS X) this adds effectively another buffer stage, so if you've got a double buffer mode it gives you triple buffer and if you had a triple buffer it'd give you a "quad" buffer (quotes here, because quad buffer is a term usually used with stereoscopic rendering).

---

What can you do about this:

- **Turn off composition**

Windows through the DWM API and MacOS X allow to turn off composition or bypass the compositor.

- **Reducing input lag**

Try to collect and integrate the user input as late as possible (use high resolution sleeps). If you've got only a very simple scene you can push the drawing quite close to the V-Sync deadline; in fact the NVidia OpenGL implementation has a vendor specific extension that allows to sleep until a specific amount of time before the next V-Sync.

If your scene is complex but is separable in parts that require low latency user input and stuff where it doesn't matter so much you can draw the higher latency stuff earlier and only at the very last moment integrate user input into it. Of course if the mouse is used to control the viewing direction, or even worse you're rendering for a VR head mounted display things are going to become difficult.

Comment: In Windows 8+, the windows compositor cannot be disabled at all. However, it doesn't actually create the same sort of latency as traditional triple buffering would. The compositor is VSYNC'd, but the application is not. The way I've seen it work on AMD and NV drivers is akin to two double-buffered systems working together. The app has a front/back buffer and the compositor effectively has a front/back. When you swap in the app, the front buffer is copied to the compositor's back buffer. You can draw way above the refresh rate without tearing or the latency associated with triple buffering.

Comment: But you may draw a lot of frames that never show up, or repeat frames twice because timing was off. It's not a perfect solution (G-Sync would be ideal), but it can actually reduce latency.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Up to, including Windows-7 composition can be disabled: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx – I wonder what kind of drugs the guys at MS were taking when deciding that you couldn't disable composition anymore in Win-8 and later.

Comment: "the NVidia OpenGL implementation has a vendor specific extension that allows to sleep until a specific amount of time before the next V-Sync" [`WGL_NV_delay_before_swap`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/wgl_delay_before_swap.txt)/[`GLX_NV_delay_before_swap`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/glx_delay_before_swap.txt)?